# Using the Swift Singleton

Tags: swift, singleton, shared

I've got the following Singleton class:

```
class Singleton {
    static let sharedInstance = Singleton()
}
```

I can find very little online about how to use the numerous swift implementations of the Singleton pattern. I have used it before in Objective-C on a previous application but to me it seemed much more straight forward.

For instance, if I wanted to create an array of custom objects that could be used anywhere in the application, how would I declare it, and how would I implement it. In my objective-C Singleton class, I create global variables in the class file, and then implement it like so:

```
singletonClass *mySingleton = [singletonClass sharedsingletonClass];
mySingleton.whatever = "blaaaah"
```

I appreciate the help! Also I'm new around here and new to Swift.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a lot of info available on singletons in Swift. Have you come across this article with your Google prowess? http://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton

But to answer your question, you can simply define anything you'd like to use normally.

```
class Singleton {
    static let sharedInstance = Singleton() // this makes singletons easy in Swift
    var stringArray = [String]()

}

let sharedSingleton = Singleton.sharedInstance

sharedSingleton.stringArray.append("blaaaah") // ["blaaaah"]

let anotherReferenceToSharedSingleton = Singleton.sharedInstance

print(anotherReferenceToSharedSingleton.stringArray) // "["blaaaah"]\n"
```

Comment: That's actually where I got my code from, however, the article is more of an analysis of each method rather than explaining what is going on. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Not a problem! In that case, you may find this post helpful: https://github.com/hpique/SwiftSingleton

Answer (score 1):

Agree with [Andrew Sowers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5807633/andrew-sowers).  Just remember that you must also declare a private initializer like this:

```
class Singleton: NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = Singleton()
    private override init() {}
}
```

Without this private init(), other objects could create their own instance:

```
let mySingleton = Singleton()
```

Now there are two instances, **Singleton.sharedInstance** and **mySingleton** - no longer a singleton!  I discovered this via a nasty bug where multiple "singletons" were firing timers and wreaking havoc.