# calling ViewController's member function from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift

I want to call a `ViewController`'s member function in `AppDelegate`'s `applicationWillResignActive` function. Not sure what is the best way to do so. I tried doing so this way:

```
let landmark = LandmarkViewController()
landmark.test()
```

but it somehow doesn't seem right. I'm essentially creating new instance of the controller instead of using the already existent one.

Comment: This may be a good place to send a notification via the [notification center](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotificationcenter). That your `LandmarkViewController` can be an observer of.

Comment: Are you using storyboard? if Yes, this is the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41136597/create-singleton-of-a-viewcontroller-in-swift-3/41136939#41136939) of what are you looking for :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve what you want is to set an observer for this notification `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` into your view controller itself.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appDidResign), name: Notification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)
}

func appDidResign() {
    // do your stuff
}

deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self) //always remember to remove any observers (you can do this in deinit in this case)
}
```

Comment: Well, I think this is not what OP is asking for, anyway it might be a goo approach...

Comment: That's true. Although I think the OP is asking this because is not aware of the Notification :)

Comment: I'd suggest to -also- add the code that related to posting the notification.

Comment: @AhmadF This notification is posted by the system, you don't need to post it yourself.

Comment: Oh, I see... sorry, I think that I really to sleep :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your above code will create a new instance. If you want to use an existing instance, then you'd need to get a reference to the existing instance somehow.

How you get the reference would depend on how you have your view controllers set. For example, if your `LandmarkViewController` is the root view controller, you can get it via your `UIWindow`, perhaps. Or, when your `LandmarkViewController` instance is created, you can pass a reference to the view controller to the app delegate. It all depends on how your app is set up.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Why should it be a comment? I was answering his question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `rootViewController` (which your `LandmarkViewController` is how I understood) from the `UIWindow`:

```
if let rootViewController = self.window?.rootViewController as LandmarkViewController {
    rootViewController.test()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think best way is add observer for notification in this class.
Some think like this:

```
class LandmarkViewController: ...
{
   ...
   func viewDidLoad()
   {
      ...
      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: applicationWillResignActive, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (notification) in
           ...
      }
   }
}
```