# Performsegue from another viewcontroller doesnt' work

Tags: storyboard, singleton, segue, viewcontroller, swift4.2

I've been using objective-C so far and decided to develop with swift since now.

I have no idea why this simple code doesn't work.

I have two viewControllers as container view from superview, one is called 'sideViewController' and the other one is 'dashViewController'.

I have a segue with identifier 'Appointment' from dashViewController to another viewController called 'nextViewController'

If i try to performsegue in dashViewController.swift, it works fine.

But why it doens't work if i try to use it in 'sideViewController'?

```
@IBAction public func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dashboardViewController")
    vc.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Appointment", sender: self) //nothing happens
}
```

In objective C, I could use singleton for dashViewController like below

```
[[MainViewController sharedViewController] performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Appointment" sender:nil];
```

But in swift, following code doesn't work

```
DashboardViewController.sharedInstance.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Appointment", sender: nil)
```

I've been struggling with this for 2 days..

Please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `buttonTapped()` function, you are creating a ***new*** instance of "dashboardViewController", and then trying to perform a segue... but you haven't added that new VC or its view to the hierarchy, so even if the segue *were* to be performed, there's nothing to see.

What you want to do is use the protocol / delegate pattern.

Create a protocol so your button tap inside "sideViewController" can tell its delegate (the "main" view controller) to tell the *existing* instance of "dashboardViewController" to perform the segue.

Protocols and delegates function the same in Swift as in Obj-C ... just different syntax.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I’ll try that

Comment: Can I ask one more? Why singleton in swift doesn’t work like objectice c? I declared singleton like this : ‘ static let shared = someViewController()’

Comment: You *could* create a singleton view controller class, but I highly recommend against it. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41136877/6257435 ... you also *could* use global vars for your child view controllers, but again, I'd recommend against that. I think you'll be much better off using the protocol / delegate pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your help!